# Connect 9 V battery to Arduino Mega 2560 directly?

Tags: arduino-mega, battery

Is it safe to connect a 9 volt battery to an Arduino Mega 2560 directly to power it?

Comment: What do you mean by "directly"?

Comment: Means the +ve terminal of battery attached to vin of arduino and -ve to ground. No extra circuit require for voltage adjustment.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. On [this](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardMega2560) page, you can see that you can safely connect 7-12V to the VIN pin.

Furthermore, you can simultaneously connect the USB; your Arduino will automatically draw power from the appropriate source.

Note that the power supply jack pin is connected to the Vin pin through a diode. Do **not** connect a battery *and* an external power supply, since a sufficiently high power supply voltage will try to charge your battery, which may be bad news for the battery.

Comment: The Vin pin is NOT the same as the power supply jack pin. They are two separate circuit nodes in the Mega schemating. Diode D1 separates the two nodes, causing a 0.7V drop when forward biased. ..... The Arduino will NOT always draw from the appropriate source. If the battery voltage is greater than the Vjack - 0.7V, the Arduino will draw mostly from the battery instead of the adapter (ac-to-dc converter), which would frequently be the appropriate course. ..... The first sentence is correct though.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I overlooked that diode. I just happened to know that the PSU pin could supply for the vin pin.

Comment: I don't want to be hypercritical, but I don't want to mislead anyone either. The diode is a smart protection to design in, but the diode itself is not smart. I also find that constantly disconnecting and connecting a header is cumbersome and if plugged into the wrong pins (by a student still learning) it can damage the board. That's why my answer suggested using the power jack. (No one like the sacrificing of an adapter to the cause though. :) )

Comment: This answer suggests the power jack as well, noting that it's connected through a diode (which comes at the price of not being able to put a large load in parallel to the arduino due to the heat production in the diode). I still don't understand why you would want to kill a power adapter to get a $1 plug.

Comment: @DouglasDaseeco Pin and sleeve diameters are invariably listed, and are easy to measure using a caliper; sleeve length usually matches, and does not really matter. Any decent electronic parts shop has them in stock, starting at around €0.70. I'm not saying you _can't_ destroy your transformers for a simple plug, but I find it ridiculous to state that as a baseline. It's like saying you need to demolish a second hand car to get new brake calipers - it could be useful at times, but it's hardly the 'normal' way of car maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

**DO NOT CONNECT IT TO Vcc, CONNECT IT TO VIn.**

By connecting it to VIn, your 9V will go from the battery, though the VReg, and then to your Arduino. This is what you **HAVE** to do. By connecting it directly to the Arduino Vcc pin, you are basicly frying it.

Note that once the battery has gone bellow 7V, it might start getting unsafe because you are not giving the Arduino enough power.

Comment: The bit about overclocking makes no sense.

Comment: You are not overclocking anything, the clock speed is fixed at 16MHz. You are generating a small amount of heat, but this is produced in the voltage regulator, nowhere near the processor.

Comment: @jwpat7, what I really meant was that you are keeping the clock speed at 16MHz, but not supplying enough power to power the Arduino at such speeds. Ain't that somewhat the definition of overclocking?

Comment: ..No it really isn't xD supplying not enough voltage *might* heat up an LDO regulator, and if you're really unlucky, it *might* heat up your MCU, but generally just causes undefined behaviour like random resets. Overclocking is an entirely different thing, and supply voltage is hardly the defining factor there.

Comment: @DatHa, overclockers typically raise the cpu voltage, instead of lowering it, and typically run the cpu at a higher frequency than it's rated for.  See eg [wikipedia Overclocking article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overclocking):  “Overclocking is configuration of computer hardware components to operate faster than certified by the original manufacturer [...] Commonly, operating voltage is also increased to maintain a component's operational stability at accelerated speeds.”  Granted, if frequency stays constant as voltage drops, the cpu ends up running faster than rated for given voltage.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Batteries are acceptable power sources for the Arduino Mega and other Arduino boards.  I've used them for years for various applications where access to AC is inconvenient, impractical, or nearly impossible.

The [Mega page on the Arduino site](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardMega)  also explicitly permits battery power.

**Helpful Guidelines**

Here are some important criteria to meet.

- The Voltage is within the published range for the Arduino model you are using, which is 7 to 12 Volts DC for the Mega 2560
- The positive of the battery supply connected to V<sub>in</sub> (NOT any of the other power pins)
- The negative of the battery supply is connected to Gnd
- Critical applications don't run under the assumption that the battery will never drop below the required 7 Volts
- The header is never plugged in backwards or in the wrong location, which would likely damage the Arduino circuitry

**Connection Safety Using Plug and Jack**

If you are connecting and disconnecting the Arduino from your battery frequently or you just want .

See the Power section of the page to make sure you never plug in the header wrong, you can connect your battery supply to the Arduino board's [existing power jack](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=4892.0).  When connecting a battery supply to an Arduino compatible plug, you can ensure that the plug's inner conductor is positive in Voltage relative to the outer sheath using a Voltmeter.

**Battery Use in Robotics and Flight Control**

A 9V battery will eventually drop in Voltage below 7V, upon which the operation of the board may fail at any time, so you may want to add more 9V batteries in parallel to extend your battery supply's life <sup>1</sup>.

Another approach common in robotics or flight control applications, to preemptively avoid erratic behavior as the battery drains below operational thresholds, is to use the low voltage detection features of the CPU.  The Atmel CPU used by the Arduino Mega 2560 has a [Brown-Out Detection feature](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-2549-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega640-1280-1281-2560-2561_datasheet.pdf).  The Atmel CPU for the Due and other boards have under-voltage detection too.

A simpler approach for critical applications is a resistor divider on an analog input is another related approach.

.....

[1] Batteries may vary in Voltage when purchased, but some small variance above or below 9V hurts neither the batteries nor the Arduino.  They will equalize themselves without dissipating (wasting) much energy, so you will get close to N times the battery life, where N is the number of 9V batteries in parallel.  See this [Electronics StackExchange Q&A](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/177204/will-connecting-two-batteries-in-parallel-increase-current-drawn-in-simple-led-c) and this [battery company article](http://www.zbattery.com/Connecting-Batteries-in-Series-or-Parallel) for more information.